# Xcode "Use of undeclared identifier"

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I know many people ask this but all the answers are specific apps so I don't understand how to work it for my app.

```
        tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Chocolate Brownie", @"Mushroom Risotto", nil];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
    {
        return [tableData count];
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;` 
    }
```

Comment: Okay.... What line are you receiving the error on? You need to be at least a little bit more specific.

Comment: on every line where I use tableData, it says use of undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the reason being ut `tableData` variable is not retained and you have assigned it via factory method with is already autoreleased.

in .h file, make it retain property and use this variable with self. in ur code.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSArray *tableData;
```

in .m,

```
@synthesize tableData;
```

then use it like:

```
self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Chocolate Brownie", @"Mushroom Risotto",      nil];
```

now you wont get any error as tableData is now retained.

do not forget to release it in `dealloc` if you are not using ARC.

Comment: it is still coming up. how do I release it in dealloc, I haven't done that before.

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare your NSArray as a property and synthetize it.
In your class definition:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *tableData;
```

And in the implementation:

```
@synthetize tableData = _tableData;
```

Comment: On that line it now says unused variable and the other lines still have the error.

Answer (score 3):

Alright then, this is a simple fix. You are receiving the error on every line that references "tableData" because it is undeclared. In other words, your app was never told what "tableData" is.

You can declare "tableData" in your .h file, it should look something like this...

```
@interface yourClassName : UITableViewController 
{
    NSArray *tableData;
}
```

**EDIT:** Go with @grasGendarme's answer if you will only be calling for this array from within this function, if you wish to use it across the controller use this answer.

**EDIT 2:** In regards to your updated question, check for this on the line thats giving you the error.

[image]

This blue arrow indicates that you have set a break point in your code on this line. You can right click the error and select delete breakpoint.

Comment: now when I go to run the app it says build succeeded but then quits once the simulator loads the app. In the code it says (on the first line I wrote in the question) "Thread 1:breakpoint 3.1"

Comment: @user1477809 Please see "Edit 2" in my answer.

Comment: @user1477809 If one of these answers was correct be sure to mark it as correct be clicking the "check mark" next to the answer.