# Undeclared identifier in xCode 5

Tags: xcode5, undeclared-identifier

I just coded this and an error (use of undeclared identifier 'RandomPosition') pops out. I'm very new to xCode and I need help please... These are the lines:

```
  RandomPosition = arc4random() %25;
  RandomPosition = RandomPosition + 75;
  Obstacle.center = CGPointMake(570, RandomPosition);

  RandomPosition = arc4random() %1;
  Floor.center = CGPointMake(550, 1);
```

Also, would any of you guys know how to make a character jump in xCode?

Thanx a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. A quick search yielded *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175938/xcode-use-of-undeclared-identifier)*. I know you are new, but try to keep in mind that some research on your part goes a *long way* to helping you out. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a data type and an identifier:

```
long RandomPosition = arc4random() %25;
```

(or it might be `int` or `unsigned` or something else).

Also, conventionally, you use Captialized words for classes and lowercase words for instances and variables, so it should probably be:

```
long randomPosition = arc4random() %25;
```

However, your identifier is legal.